# What is the difference between FIQ and IRQ interrupt system?

Tags: arm, interrupt, drivers, microprocessors, isr

I want to know the difference between FIQ and IRQ interrupt system in
any microprocessor, e.g: ARM926EJ.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

A feature of modern ARM CPUs (and some others).

From the patent:

> A method of performing a fast
>   interrupt in a digital data processor
>   having the capability of handling more
>   than one interrupt is provided. When a
>   fast interrupt request is received a 
>   flag is set and the program counter
>   and condition code registers are
>   stored on a stack. At the end of the
>   interrupt servicing routine the return
>   from interrupt instructions retrieves 
>   the condition code register which
>   contains the status of the digital
>   data processor and  checks to see
>   whether the flag has been set or not.
>   If the flag is set it indicates that a
>   fast interrupt was serviced and
>   therefore only the program counter is
>   unstacked.

In other words, an FIQ is just a higher priority interrupt request, that is prioritized by disabling IRQ and other FIQ handlers during request servicing.  Therefore, no other interrupts can occur during the processing of the active FIQ interrupt.

Comment: Not to take away from the answer, but what's in a patent doesn't necessarily say anything about what's implemented, so I wouldn't really consider it an authoritative reference.

Answer (score 174):

ARM calls `FIQ` the *fast interrupt*, with the implication that `IRQ` is *normal priority*. In any real system, there will be many more sources of interrupts than just two devices and there will therefore be some external hardware interrupt controller which allows masking, prioritization etc. of these multiple sources and which drives the interrupt request lines to the processor.

To some extent, this makes the distinction between the two interrupt modes redundant and many systems do not use `nFIQ` at all, or use it in a way analogous to the non-maskable (`NMI`) interrupt found on other processors (although `FIQ` is software maskable on most ARM processors).

> So why does ARM call FIQ "fast"?

1. FIQ mode has its own dedicated banked registers, `r8-r14`. R14 is the link register which holds the return address(+4) from the FIQ. But if your FIQ handler is able to be written such that it only uses `r8-r13`, it can take advantage of these banked registers in two ways:

   - One is that it does not incur the overhead of pushing and popping any registers that are used by the interrupt service routine (ISR). This can save a significant number of cycles on both entry and exit to the ISR.
   - Also, the handler can rely on values persisting in registers from one call to the next, so that for example `r8` may be used as a pointer to a hardware device and the handler can rely on the same value being in `r8` the next time it is called.
2. FIQ location at the end of the exception vector table (`0x1C`) means that if the FIQ handler code is placed directly at the end of the vector table, no branch is required - the code can execute directly from `0x1C`. This saves a few cycles on entry to the ISR.
3. FIQ has higher priority than IRQ. This means that when the core takes an FIQ exception, it automatically masks out IRQs. An IRQ cannot interrupt the FIQ handler. The opposite is not true - the IRQ does not mask FIQs and so the FIQ handler (if used) can interrupt the IRQ. Additionally, if both IRQ and FIQ requests occur at the same time, the core will deal with the FIQ first.

> So why do many systems not use FIQ?

1. FIQ handler code typically cannot be written in C - it needs to be written directly in assembly language. If you care sufficiently about ISR performance to want to use FIQ, you probably wouldn't want to leave a few cycles on the table by coding in C in any case, but more importantly the C compiler will not produce code that follows the restriction on using only registers `r8-r13`. Code produced by a C compiler compliant with ARM's `ATPCS` procedure call standard will instead use registers `r0-r3` for scratch values and will not produce the correct `cpsr` restoring return code at the end of the function.
2. All of the interrupt controller hardware is typically on the IRQ pin. Using FIQ only makes sense if you have a single highest priority interrupt source connected to the nFIQ input and many systems do not have a single permanently highest priority source. There is no value connecting multiple sources to the FIQ and then having software prioritize between them as this removes nearly all the advantages the FIQ has over IRQ.

Comment: FIQ is used for Secure Worlds in ARM TrustZone implementations, to distinguish interrupts from "secure" interrupt sources. The precise determination of what might be a secure interrupt source and how that should be handled differently from a normal interrupt depends on the threat and implementation models.

Comment: GCC and LLVM both lack the optimizations needed for FIQ code. They will continue using registers r0 to r7 instead of r8 and above. And so the generated code push/pops them on/from the stack. Also, when calling a function, the compilers will continue to use the standard ABI (the function may alter r0 to r3). Pretty quickly, the generated assembly becomes standard and is inefficient.

Answer (score 80):

**FIQ** or *fast interrupt* is often referred to as **Soft DMA** in some ARM references.
Features of the **FIQ** are,

1. Separate mode with banked register including stack, link register and R8-R12.
2. Separate FIQ enable/disable bit.
3. Tail of vector table (which is always in cache and mapped by MMU).

The last feature also gives a slight advantage over an *IRQ* which must branch.

### A speed demo in 'C'

Some have quoted the difficulty of coding in assembler to handle the FIQ.  `gcc` has annotations to code a **FIQ** handler.  Here is an example,

```
void  __attribute__ ((interrupt ("FIQ"))) fiq_handler(void)
{
    /* registers set previously by FIQ setup. */
    register volatile char *src asm ("r8");  /* A source buffer to transfer. */
    register char *uart asm ("r9");          /* pointer to uart tx register. */
    register int size asm ("r10");           /* Size of buffer remaining. */
    if(size--) {
        *uart = *src++;
    }
}
```

This translates to the following almost good assembler,

```
00000000 <fiq_handler>:
   0:   e35a0000        cmp     sl, #0
   4:   e52d3004        push    {r3}            ; use r11, r12, etc as scratch.
   8:   15d83000        ldrbne  r3, [r8]
   c:   15c93000        strbne  r3, [r9]
  10:   e49d3004        pop     {r3}            ; same thing.
  14:   e25ef004        subs    pc, lr, #4
```

The assembler routine at `0x1c` might look like,

```
   tst     r10, #0    ; counter zero?
   ldrbne  r11, [r8]  ; get character.
   subne   r10, #1    ; decrement count
   strbne  r11, [r9]  ; write to uart
   subs    pc, lr, #4 ; return from FIQ.
```

A real *UART* probably has a ready bit, but the code to make a high speed *soft DMA* with the FIQ would only be 10-20 instructions.  The main code needs to poll the FIQ `r10` to determine when the buffer is finished.  Main (non-interrupt code) may transfer and setup the banked **FIQ** registers by using the `msr` instruction to switch to **FIQ** mode and transfer non-banked R0-R7 to the banked R8-R13 registers.

Typically RTOS interrupt latency will be 500-1000 instructions.  For Linux, it maybe 2000-10000 instructions.  Real DMA is always preferable, however, for high frequency simple interrupts (like a buffer transfer), the **FIQ** can provide a solution.

As the **FIQ** is about speed, you shouldn't consider it if you aren't secure in coding in assembler (or willing to dedicate the time).  Assembler written by an infinitely running programmer will be faster than a compiler.  Having GCC assist can help a novice.

### Latency

As the **FIQ** has a separate mask bit it is almost ubiquitously enabled.  On earlier ARM CPUs (such as the ARM926EJ), some atomic operations had to be implemented by masking interrupts.  Still even with the most advanced Cortex CPUs, there are occasions where an OS will mask interrupts.  Often the service time is not critical for an interrupt, but the time between signalling and servicing.  Here, the **FIQ** also has an advantage.

### Weakness

The **FIQ** is not scalable.  In order to use multiple `FIQ` sources, the banked registers must be shared among interrupt routines.  Also, code must be added to determine what caused the interrupt/FIQ.  The **FIQ** is generally a *one trick pony*.

If your interrupt is highly complex (network driver, USB, etc), then the FIQ probably makes little sense.  This is basically the same statement as multiplexing the interrupts.  The *banked* registers give 6 free variables to use which **never load from memory**.  Register are faster than memory.  Registers are faster than L2-cache.  Registers are faster than L1-cache.  Registers are fast.  If you can not write a routine that runs with 6 variables, then the **FIQ** is not suitable.  Note: You can double duty some register with *shifts* and *rotates* which are free on the ARM, if you use 16 bit values.

Obviously the **FIQ** is more complex.  OS developers want to support multiple interrupt sources.  Customer requirements for a **FIQ** will vary and often they realize they should just let the customer *roll their own*.  Usually support for a **FIQ** is limited as any support is likely to detract from the main benefit, **SPEED**.

### Summary

Don't bash my friend the **FIQ**.  It is a system programers one trick against stupid hardware.  It is not for everyone, but it has its place.  When all other attempts to reduce latency and increase ISR service frequency has failed, the **FIQ** can be your only choice (or a better hardware team).

It also possible to use as a **panic** interrupt in some safety critical applications.

Comment: As an addendum, it is pretty much mandatory for a secure world OS (ARM TrustZone) to use the **FIQ**.  However, in this case it functions as a normal interrupt handler, not the traditional **SoftDMA** role.  The *normal world* uses the normal **IRQ** mechanism and the secure uses the **FIQ**.

Comment: Just wondering why you are not reading ACK and sending EOI in your handler

Comment: @Charvak  That is interrupt controller specific; you are thinking *GIC*.  Some interrupt controllers will automatically clear (Ie, uart ready goes *not ready* when a character is written).  It is a hypothetical example (for a generic answer; the OP had an ARM926) and not an actual working example.  Put the *GIC* base in a FIQ register and do the `ACK` and `EOI`, if that is the controller you have.

Comment: Local register variables don't do what you might think they do. They don't reserve the register for a certain variable. In fact, gcc will only guarantee that the variable's value is in the specified registry when inline assembly is executed that has the specified variable an input or output parameter. At any other time, the register may be used for other data. In particular, I believe that gcc does not understand that of `src` has to be in register `r8` when the function returns.

However, global register variables seem to be suitable here, as they do reserve the registers.

Comment: @Sven That maybe correct.  I really only meant it to provide a skeleton of the assembler.  I may retry to see if I can get the compiler to generate an actual FIQ routines.  However, the FIQ banked registers are not a concept that is normal to GCC, so hand coding (especially code that may need to relocate) may actually be more efficient than working through all the nuances of getting GCC to generate proper FIQ code.

Comment: It is known that GCC tends to use registers r0 to r7 even though r8 and friends could be used. It's a pity, but GCC is not yet optimal for writing FIQ handlers, IMHO. For reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48429

Answer (score 6):

Chaos has already answered well, but an additional point not covered so far is that FIQ is at the end of the vector table and so it's common/traditional to just start the routine right there, whereas the IRQ vector is usually just that. (ie a jump to somewhere else). Avoiding that extra branch immediately after a full stash and context switch is a slight speed gain.

Answer (score 5):

another reason is in case of FIQ, lesser number of register is needed to push in the stack, FIQ mode has R8 to R14_fiq registers

Answer (score 3):

FIQ is higher priority, and can be introduced while another IRQ is being handled.  The most critical resource(s) are handled by FIQ's, the rest are handled by IRQ's.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.sys.arm/2005-09/msg00084.html

Essentially, FIQ will be of the highest priority with multiple, lower priority IRQ sources.

Answer (score 1):

FIQs are higher priority, no doubt, remaining points i am not sure..... FIQs will support high speed data transfer (or) channel processing, where high speed data processes is required we use FIQs and generally IRQs are used normal interrupt handlling.

Answer (score 0):

No any magic about FIQ. FIQ just can interrupt any other IRQ which is being served,this is why it is called 'fast'. The system reacts faster on these interrupts but the rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It Depends how we design interrupt handlers, as FIQ is at last it may not need one branch instruction, also it has unique set of r8-r14 registers so next time we come back to FIQ interrupt we do not need to push/pop up the stack. Ofcourse it saves some cycles, but again it is not wise to have more handlers serving one FIQ and yes FIQ is having more priority but it is not any reason to say it handles the interrupt faster, both IRQ/FIQ run at same CPU frequency, So they must be running at same speed.

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is not about speed of execution but latency, using FIQ with the servicing routine (ISR) written in C* instead of assembler may result in leaner code than the standard approach. Think of one task that needs to be executed with a lower latency than the execution time of each of several other infrequent tasks.

The standard approach: The IRQs for the infrequent tasks would only set notification flags and return, so that the frequent task's ISR can be served with low latency. Outside of any ISR, the work of the infrequent tasks is done whenever the corresponding flag is set.

Using FIQ, you would not need notifications, but each task would run fully as ISR.

*) Given that your C compiler knows how to implement FIQ ISRs. Citing, for example, [ARM Optimizing C/C++ Compiler v18.1.0.LTS User's Guide (Rev. R)](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spnu151r/spnu151r.pdf):

> 5.10.15 **The INTERRUPT Pragma** enables you to handle interrupts directly with C code. [...] The registers that are saved and the return sequence depend upon the interrupt type.

Answer (score -6):

This may be wrong.  All I know is that FIQ stands for Fast Interrupt Request and that IRQ stands for Interrupt Request.  Judging from these names, I will guess that a FIQ will be handled(thrown?) faster than an IRQ.  It probably has something to do with the design of the processor where an FIQ will interrupt the process faster than an IRQ.  I apologize if I'm wrong, but I normally do higher level programming, I'm just guessing right now.