# How many instructions does Linux kernel need in order to handle an interrupt on an arm cortex A9?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, irq

I would like to estimate the amount of opcodes it takes a `ARM` `cortex A9` single core to handle an IRQ.

Assuming I work with Linux kernel `3.4`, how many opcodes it takes to call the `irq` and execute the `irq_handler` ?

Comment: Why opcodes? Do you mean instruction or clock cycles?

Comment: Why do you ask? Isn't the admissible interrupt frequency, or the latency (from interrupt hardware impulse to start of handler either in the kernel or a signal handler in the application) more relevant?

Comment: @BillPringlemeir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698229/what-is-the-irq-latency-due-to-the-operating-system please fill free to add topics to the question and answer it

Comment: @TurboJ can you specify the difference between opcodes and instructions?

Comment: @0x90 An "opcode", operation code, is only the binary code to code a specific operation so that the CPU knows which operation to perform. The instruction is the opcode + the other bits encoding the parameters for example.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to do it? I am also working on a similar problem and I am trying to model the worst case scenario when a baremetal application runs on a ARM cortex A9 cpu. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Nuetrino The bottleneck is the controller. the time it takes the CPU handles a interrupt is negligible. about 20 nano seconds. if you make some research, please share it with us. thanks

Comment: Did you manage to theoretically bind the number of clock cycles ( worst case ) it would take to respond to a interrupt? I am researching how the jitter would be in cases where the i) task is running as a bare metal program ii) when it is running as FREE Rtos part. So for my 1st scenario my interrupt passes through the GIC and I am looking to calculate the number of instructions/cycles ( worst case)it executes before it reaches the ISR do you have pointers to   check this?there is something similar here for Arm9 http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0164a/CIHDFIDE.html

Comment: I will add the results here once i am done with my project.

Comment: @0x90 are you sure the bottleneck is the controller? because as far theoretical knowledge goes ( according to the documentation from ARM), latency in the controller seems it can be bound ( 2-3 gclks which is 1/4 of the clk) ? Would you mind sharing how did you come to that conclusion? I am yet to do the implementation though. btw i am assuming you are talking about the pl190 interrupt controller in ARM-Cortex A9.

Comment: also there are 2 legacy interrupts in pl190 which bypasses the distributor and cpu-interface logic which are hardwired to a cpu ( i assume). I think this can be used to check the bottleneck due to the controller itself. What do you think?

Comment: @0x90 could you tell me how did you conclude that the bottleneck is in the controller?. I have made my experiments and I get around 500 Nanoseconds (with a spreading of 200 Nano seconds) When I run a Bare metal application. This is addition of the latency involved with the Distributor and CPU interface of the GIC ( runs 1/4th of the CPU clock) + Time spent in Exception handling in ARM. So I am really curious how did you find out the bottle neck due to the controller. I am thinking of using Legacy interrupts ( which bypasses  distributor) to check. DId you do the same?

Answer (score 8):

You question is related how to calculate the [**interrupt latency**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698229/what-is-the-irq-latency-due-to-the-operating-system) of Linux.  At least you might be interested in how long it takes before your interrupt even starts.  We will ignore this aspect of `irqs` here.

A simple way is to toggle a `GPIO` and use a scope to measure the interrupt.  You may even toggle the `GPIO` multiple times to see the time different phases take.  This [Window CE link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms836535.aspx) shows an example measuring for latency.  Some interrupt controller (such as the IMX) have I/O multiplexing modes where an interrupt number will raise/lower a particular I/O line.  Alternatively, you can add code to toggle the line (see below for routines).

The source for the primary interrupt handling is in [entry-armv.S](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S;hb=HEAD).  There are macros defined for the interrupt controller you use and these depend on the `.config` file.  For instance, there is pre-emptive interrupts, multi-interrupt controllers, SMP, etc.  The *primary* vectors are defined at the bottom of **entry-armv.S**.  The general gist is that the current operating mode is inspected and then either `__irq_usr` or `__irq_svc` is taken.  These routines have a different pre-ample to store state, but they both end up calling the `irq_handler` macro.  The `_irq_usr` has stuff about `cmpxchg`, but if you specify and ARM cortex in your `.config`, this won't apply. The main difference will be the possible context switch after the IRQ occurs in user mode.  Your machine defines `mach/entry-macro.S` which are assembler macros to access the interrupt controller and get an interrupt number.  It then jumps to generic `irq` [handling code](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=kernel/irq/handle.c;hb=HEAD) in the top level *kernel* directory.

So the second way would be to inspect the code and calculate it directly.  This is probably easier if you look at the source, compile your kernel and then do an `objdump --disassemble` on the **vmlinux** image and look for these symbols.  You will see the `irq_handler` macro expanded and it should jump to your IRQ code eventually.

As you can see from the source, there is also [`TRACE_IRQFLAGS`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/irqflags-tracing.txt;hb=HEAD).  You can check to see if this is available on the Cortex A9 you are using with `make menuconfig` (and type `/TRACE_IRQFLAGS`).  I don't know if it is available or not.

There are variations such as,

1. Interrupt from User/SVC mode.
2. Other interrupt currently running.
3. Code that is interrupted (such as stm/ldm) may take some time to complete.
4. Page faults in your ISR.  Some Alsa drivers can fault with unallocated pages in at least some Linux versions.
5. Conditionals in your ISR.

Measuring on a scope will show the **jitter** in `IRQ` servicing.  Examining the instructions will generally show that the `IRQ` may never be serviced; for example if higher priority interrupts constantly pre-empt/prevent the `IRQ`.  Probably you need to do both to fully optimize for a hard deadline.

Often you don't care how long the whole `IRQ` takes but the time between the `IRQ` line being raised and writing/reading some peripheral register.  For instance, a `FIFO` may have limited depth and if the latency between the IRQ occurring and reading the `FIFO` register  is greater than **FIFO_Size x BPS**, then you have issues with the `FIFO` overflowing.

My post seems frustrating.  There is a saviour.  The [FIQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973933/what-is-the-difference-between-fiq-and-irq-interrupt-system).  See: Linux kernel [fiq.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/fiq.h?h=v6.8-rc4) for an API to use FIQs in your driver.  The `FIQ` infra-structure is a lot faster, but the kernel facilities you can use are far less!

**Edit:** The [Cortex A9 technical reference](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0388i/DDI0388I_cortex_a9_r4p1_trm.pdf) has instruction counts in appendix B.  Most ARM instruction are a single cycle on most architectures, except memory load/store, multiples and branches.  Follow the 3rd and 4th paragraphs above to find the complete instruction path to handle a Linux interrupt for your configuration and just **add it up**; for an *estimate* (as the original question asks) you can just count the instructions as they are generally a single cycle.

Answer (score 6):

Whilst you can calculate the theoretical minimum number of core cycles by inspection of the source code,  the number actually taken is far less certain due to the effects of caching, memory and memory controller performance, what the other core is doing at the time and various other factors dependant on the micro-architecture of the ARM processor in question.

I suspect you would be better off measuring the actual interrupt latency performance of your system, either using a digital 'scope or performance counters.

Of course, for hard real-time applications, you need to know the *worst case* interrupt latency - which includes the worst case of *all* of these factors.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail, how to measure the worst case theoretically from source code? Thanks

Comment: I don't see any way of doing this without am accurate register-level simulation of the entire CPU and memory subsystem (e.g. of the design in Verilog or VHDL)- and a workload to run on it so that you can model the effects of various caches in the device.    Again, I think you'd have to measure it and make some assumptions.

Comment: you surely can roughly bound it. if you can bound the number of particles in planet I think you can bound how an ARM cpu work in the best worst case

Comment: Absolutely - the difference is going to be a the odd cache miss here, and some memory latency there. I suspect we're looking at tenths of a micro-second.  The Linux kernel is responsible for *way* more latency itself. What is going to be hard work is estimating these effects based on reference manuals and schematics for your system.

Comment: Worst case is all cache misses, isn't it?