# how do I get the time spent by the linux kernel servicing interrupts

Tags: c, linux, performance, linux-kernel, irq

I want to track down jitter in a piece of code and I know there are many potential sources ( task switch, system calls, cache misses, moving task to another CPU, cpu throttling, etc ) and I know how to track all of those but the only one I don't know how to track is time the kernel spent servicing interrupts.  The data is in /proc/stat but that measures time in soft-irq and irq at a low resolution and I'm looking for something at a much finer resolution.

Is there a way to get the time, down to the nanosecond or at least microsecond, spent by the kernel servicing interrupts?

Comment: You can compile a custom kernel that flips a gpio on interrupt enter/exit, then trace the timing on a logic analyzer.

Comment: Any attempt to measure something will affect the something (in varying degree).  So external measurement is preferred, such as @TJD 's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes put a printk before and after the calling to `handle_IRQ` the timer on the screen is usually the high resolution one:

```
 86 /*
 87  * asm_do_IRQ is the interface to be used from assembly code.
 88  */
 89 asmlinkage void __exception_irq_entry
 90 asm_do_IRQ(unsigned int irq, struct pt_regs *regs)
 91 {
 92         handle_IRQ(irq, regs);
 93 }
 94
```

If you ask about the `irq_latency` see these nice answers:

[What is the irq latency due to the operating system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698229/what-is-the-irq-latency-due-to-the-operating-system)

Comment: Careful, though: keep in mind that `printk()` is not free. If kernel messages are being printed to a console, your measurements may end up dominated by the time it takes to generate that output!

Comment: agreed you can use the cycle counter depends on your platform and calculate the time difference by divide the delta with the core frequency.