# How to compare two implementations of the same algorithm? (by examine their Assembly code)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, assembly, x86, arm

Assume I have two implementations of the same algorithm in assembly. I would like to know by examining the two snippets codes which one is faster.

The parameters I thought one might take into account are: number of op-codes, number of branches, number of function frames.

My questions are:

> 1. Can I assume each opcode execution is one cycle ?
> 2. What is the overhead of branch which break the pipeline ?
> 3. What are the effects and overhead of calling a function ?
> 4. Is there a difference in the analysis between ARM and x86 ?

The question is theoretical since I have two implementations; one 130 instructions long and one is 184 instructions long.

And I would like to know if it is definitely true to say the 130 instructions long  snippet is faster than the 184 instructions long implementation?

## "BETTER == FASTER"

Comment: Have you tried executing them?

Comment: At the assembly level, the answer will always depend on the hardware you're running on. You can't generalize things like number of cycles per op code.

Comment: What do you consider "better"? Faster, shorter, maintainable, ...

Comment: It's a lot more complex than this.

Comment: ARM can execute ~2 instruction per cycle; it has better code density; non-destructive arithmetic due to almost orthogonal 3-parameter opcode format, conditional setting of flags, more versatile addressing mode, all instructions are conditional -- and about 30% of the gigahertzes. Thus, unless the code is dominated by arbitrary conditionals/if statements, Intel will win with a factor of 2-3x.

Comment: We have 35 years worth of x86 implementations. They are not even close to each other in instruction timings. What is fast on one is slow on the next model, and vice versa.

Comment: You have inspired me to ask a question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942436/post-process-objdump-disassemble-with-arm-cycle-counts

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen arm doesn't have a better code density compared to intel. what do you mean by non-destructive arithmetic due to almost orthogonal 3-parameter opcode format ?

Comment: Intel's arithmetic with `add eax,ebx` destroys eax. `lea eax, [ebx+ecx]` is Intel's only exception to that. Arm has freely selectable target on virtually every instruction: `or r4, r5, r9`. Intel can be optimized for higher code density at the expense of speed. Such trade off is not that visible on arm (which can be toggled to thumb16 mode with intel like destructive arithmetic for selected tasks).

Comment: How is one 32-bit instruction `or r4,r5,r9` better than two 16-bit instructions `mov eax, ebx ; or eax, ecx`? Seems pretty similar to me, and do exactly the same.

Comment: That particular example has two drawbacks -- consumption of _decoding_ resources (which are limited per clock cycle) and taken that you use `mov dst, src` format, it contains an extra dependency. (It's trivial dependency and could probably be resolved in some advanced pipeline...)

Comment: @artlessnoise can you add a link to your nice question in your answer?

Comment: @artlessnoise the question is the nice your answer is awesome. :) yes that is the one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely not true to say that the 130 instruction code is faster than the 184 instruction code.  it is very easy to have 1000 instructions run faster than 100 and vice versa on either of these platforms.

> 1 Can I assume each opcode execution is one cycle ?

Start by looking at the advertised mips/mhz, although a marketing number it gives a rough idea of what is possible.  If the number is greater than one then more than one instruction per clock is possible.

> 2 What is the overhead of branch which break the pipeline ?

Anywhere from absolutely no affect to a very dramatic affect, on either system.  one clock to hundreds are the potential penalty.

> 3 What are the effects and overhead of calling a function ?

Depends heavily on the function, and the function calling the function.  Depending on the calling convention you might have to save registers to the stack, or rearrange the contents of registers to prepare for the parameters for the function to be called.  If passing a struct by value a copy of the struct may need to be made on the stack, the bigger the struct passed the bigger the copy.  once in the function a stack frame may need to be prepared, etc, etc.  There are many factors involved.  This question and answer are also independent of platform.

> 4 Is there a difference in the analysis between ARM and x86 ?

yes and no, both systems use all the modern tricks of pipelining, branch prediction, etc to keep the mips/mhz up.  ARM is going to give a better mips per mhz than x86, x86 being variable instruction length might give more instructions per unit cache.  How you analyze the cache, and memory and peripheral systems in the systems side of the analysis is roughly the same.  The comparison of the instructions and core are similar and different depending on what aspects you are analyzing.  The arm is not microcoded, the x86 likely is so you dont really see how many registers there really are, things like that.  at the same time the x86 you can get a better look at the memory system with the arm, since they are generally not system on a chip.  Depending on what ARM chip you buy you may lose a lot of the visibility in the boundaries of the chip, might not see all the memory and peripheral busses, for example. (x86 is changing that by putting pcie on chip now for example)  in the case of something in the cortex-a class you mentioned you would have similar edge of chip visibility as those would use larger/cheaper dram based memory off chip rather than microcontroller like on chip resources.

Bottom line your final question:

"And I would like to know if it is definitely true to say the 130 instructions long snippet is faster than the 184 instructions long implementation?"

It is definitely NOT TRUE to say the 130 instruction snippet is faster than the 184 instruction snippet.  It might be faster it might be slower and it might be about the same.  With a lot more information we might be able to make a pretty good statement or it may still be non-deterministic.  it is easy to choose 100 instructions that execute faster than 1000 instructions and likewise easy to choose 1000 instructions that execute faster than 100 instructions (even if I were to add no branching and no loops, just linear execution)

Comment: can you rephrase this sentence?  If the number is greater than one then more than one instruction per clock is possible.

Comment: 2 million operations per second on a computer clocked at 1 million cycles per second means 2 mips /megaherts which also means 2 instructions per cycle, for example.  1.25 mips/mhz means 1.25 instructions per cycle so more than one instruction per cycle.

Answer (score 11):

Without wanting to be flippant, the answers are

> 1. no
> 2. that depends on your hardware
> 3. that depends on your hardware
> 4. yes

You would really need to test things on your target hardware, or have a simulator that understands your hardware fully, in order to answer your question the way you meant to...

For the last part of your question, you need to define "better"…better.

Comment: Good answer. #3 depends not only on the hardware, but also on the calling model.

Comment: @JimMischel: Yes. In particular, the problem is even more complicated with newest architectures (dual core, quad core, ecc...). It's not so simple obtain a simple model to use for performance measuring.

Comment: Even #1 **depends on the hardware**.  If you have a particularly slow memory interface with the cache off, you will just be waiting for memory.

Comment: @BillPringlemeir - the answer "no" _includes_ memory access issues. It also depends on the instruction and the target. The question was "can I assume", the answer is "no you can't assume". I suppose I could elaborate in the answer - not sure if it is warranted. What do you think?

Comment: It is a hard question to answer exactly; everything depends on the hardware. I just tried to give some guidance in my answer.

Comment: It also depends on whether anybody has spent any energy tuning the code.   A few well placed cache alignments of data or code, careful use of registers, may make a fairly significant difference in the performance of the code.

Comment: @Floris can you please enrich your answer ?

Comment: @0x90 - Bill already mentioned all the points I would add to "enrich" my answer... It would look like plagiarism if I repeated it.

Answer (score 8):

Since you asked about a [Cortex A9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674392/how-many-instructions-does-linux-kernel-need-in-order-to-handle-an-interrupt-on), the [data sheet](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0388i/DDI0388I_cortex_a9_r4p1_trm.pdf) has instruction cycle counts in **appendix B**. These counts generally assume that the memory bus is fast enough to keep the CPU busy.  In reality this is rarely the case.  Many video/audio algorithms will have a big win in how they access memory.

### One cycle per op

Of course you can't assume this if you want an exact count.  However, if you are deciding which algorithm to choose, you can get a feel for the best algorithm by looking at the instructions in the **inner** loop.  Here, your `cache` should allow the code to execute as per the instruction counts in the data sheet.  If the counts are close, then you probably need to look at each instruction.  Load/stores are more expensive and usually multiples, etc. Some algorithms, especially crytographic, will have big wins by using assembler that doesn't map well to `C`.  For example, `clz`, `ror`, using the carry for multi-word arithmetic, etc.

### Branch overhead

Look in **Appendix B**, or whatever data sheet has cycle counts for your processor.  For an ARM926 it is about 3 cycles.  The compiler only generates two conditional opcodes in a row to avoid branching, otherwise, it branches.  If the algorithm is large, the branch may disrupt the cache.  A **hard** answer depends on your CPU, cache, and memory.  According to the Cortex A9 datasheet (B.5), there is only one cycle overhead to a fixed branch.

### Function overhead

This is much the same as the **branch overhead**.  However, the compiler will also have an influence. <sup>[noted by Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56778/jim-mischel)</sup>  Does it cache align functions.  Does the compiler perform **leaf function** optimizations, etc.  With modern `gcc` versions, if all the functions are static, the compiler will generally in-line when it is advantageous.  If the algorithms are particularly large, a register spill may be advantageous.  However, with your example of 130/184 instructions, this seems unlikely.  The compiler **options** will obviously effect the overhead.  You can use `objdump -S` to examine the prologue/epilogue and then determine the number of cycles for your hardware.

### ARM verus x86

Of course there is a technical difference in the cycle counts.  The `CISC` x86 also has *variable* instruction size.  This complicates the analysis.  It is slightly easier on the ARM.

Normally, you want to ball park things and then actually run them with a profiler.  The estimates can help guide development of the algorithms.  Loop/memory tuning, etc for your hardware.  Something like `instruction emulation`, `page` or `alignment faults`, etc may be dominant and make all the cycle count analysis meaningless.  If the algorithm is in `user space`, per-emption, may negate cache wins from run to run.  It is possible that one algorithm will work better in a little loaded system and the other will work better under a higher load.

### A note on *cycle* counts

See the [post-process objdump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942436/post-process-objdump-disassemble-with-arm-cycle-counts) for some complications in getting cycle counts.  Basically a typical CPU is several phases (a pipe line) and different conditions can cause *stalls*.  As CPU's become more complex, the pipe line typically gets longer, meaning there are more conditions or phases which can stall.  However, *cycle count* estimates can be helpful in guiding development of an algorithm and evaluating them.  Things like *memory timing* or *branch prediction* can be just as important, depending on the algorithm.  Ie, *cycle counts* are not completely useless, but they are not complete either.  Profiling should confirm *actual* algorithm times.  If they diverge, instruction re-ordering, pre-fetching and other techniques may bring them closer.  The fact that *cycle counts* and active profiling diverge can be helpful in itself.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is almost entirely meaningless: **It probably depends on your input.**

Most CPUs have something resembling a branch misprediction penalty (e.g. traditional ARM which throws away an instruction fetch/decode on any taken branch, IIRC). ARM and x86 also allow conditional execution, which *can be* faster than branching. If either of these are dependent on input data, then different inputs will follow different code paths.

Perhaps one version heavily uses conditional execution, which is wasteful when the condition is false. Perhaps another was compiled using some profiling information that performs no branches (except the return at the end) for a specific case. There are many, many reason why a compiler can take the same source and produce an "optimized" output which is faster for one input and slower for another.

*Many* optimizations have this characteristic — for example, aligning the start of a loop to 16 bytes helps on some processors, but not when the loop is only executed once.

Answer (score 2):

Some text book answer to this question from [Cortex
™
-A Series Programmer’s Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0013c/index.html), `chapter 17`.

> > Although cycle timing information can be found in the Technical Reference Manual (TRM) for the processor that you are using, it is very difficult to work out how many cycles even a trivial piece of code will take to execute. The movement of instructions through the pipeline is dependent on the progress of the surrounding instructions and can be significantly affected by memory system 
> >     activity. Pending loads or instruction fetches which miss in the cache can stall code for tens of cycles. Standard data processing instructions (logical and arithmetic) will take only one or two cycles to execute, but this does not give the full picture. Instead, we must use profiling tools, or the system performance monitor built-in to the processor, to extract useful information about performance.

Also read under `17.4 Cortex-A9 micro-architecture optimizations` which answers your question very very much.