# Post process `objdump --disassemble` with ARM cycle counts

Tags: gcc, open-source, arm, objdump

Is there a script available for post processing some `objdump --disassemble` output to annotate with cycle counts?  Especially for the ARM family.  <strike>Most of the time this would only be a pattern match with a table lookup for the count.  I guess annotations like `+5M` for five memory cycles might be needed.</strike>  Perl, python, bash, `C`, etc are fine.  I think this can be done generically, but I am interested in the **ARM**, which has an *orthogonal* instruction set. Here is a thread on the [68HC11](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/gnu-m68hc11/message/694) doing the same thing.  The script would need an CPU **model** option to select the appropriate cycle counts; I think these counts already exist in the `gcc` machine description.

I don't think there is an `objdump` switch for this, but RTFM would be great.

**Edit:** To clarify, assumptions such as best case memory sub-system as will be the case when the code executes from cache are fine.  The goal is not a 100% accurate cycle count as per some running machine.  It is possible to get a reasonable estimate, otherwise compiler design would be impossible.

As [DWelch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16007/dwelch) points out, a simple running total is not possible with deep pipelined architecture, like more recent Cortex chips.  The `objdump` post processing would have to look at surrounding opcodes.  A gcc plug-in is more likely to be able to accomplish this and as that is new (4.5+), I don't think such a thing exists.  A script for the ARM926 is certainly possible and fairly simple.

The memory latency doesn't matter.  The memory controller is like another `CPU`.  It is doing it's business while the CPU is doing arithmetic, etc.  A good/well tuned algorithm will [parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) the memory accesses with the computations.  By counting loads/store and cycles you can determine how much parallelism is accomplished, when you actively profile with a timer.  The pipeline is significant due to interlocks between registers, but a cycle count for [basic blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block) can reliably be calculated and used even on modern ARM processors; this is too complex for a simple script.

Comment: FYI, ARM doesn't publish cycle timings for their recent CPUs (e.g. Cortex-A5/A7/A15)

Comment: @Maratyszcza:Interesting.  I looked and I don't see any.  It say **low cycle count** for the ARM7-a, so I guess this means single clock, except for memory issues. How can anyone write a compiler then?  Gcc seems to have a description. http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/arm/cortex-a5.md;hb=HEAD

Comment: Different ARMv7-A CPUs have different cycle timings (and code optimized for one CPU will be suboptimal on another).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an online tool which [estimates cycle counts on Cortex-A8](http://pulsar.webshaker.net/ccc/index.php). However, this CPU is quite old, and programs optimized for it might be suboptimal on newer CPUs.

AFAIK ARM also provides Cortex-A9 and Cortex-A5 [cycle-accurate emulators in their RVDS software](http://www.arm.com/products/tools/models/fast-models/index.php), but it is quite expensive.

Comment: +1 for something demonstrating it is possible; only a fool would think these tools are 100% accurate.  I am hoping for something open-source, and more generic; In particular, I don't have a Cortex.

Comment: The fast models are not cycle-accurate. To make a joke, those would be slow models :) -- there are no publicly available cycle-accurate models.

Answer (score 4):

Cycle counts are not something that can be assessed by looking at the instruction alone on a modern high end ARM.  There is a lot of runtime state that affects the real world retirement rate of an instruction.  Does the data it needs exist in the cache?  Does the instruction have any dependencies on previous instruction results?  If so, what latencies does the forwarding unit remove?  How full is the load/store buffer?  What kind of memory mapping is it touching?  How full are the processor pipelines that this instruction needs?  Are there synchronizing instructions in the stream?  Has speculation brought forward some data it depends on?  What is the state of the register renamer?  Have conditional instructions been filling the pipeline or was the decoder smart enough to skip them completely?  What are the ratios between the core clock and the bus and memory clocks?  What's the size of the branch prediction table?

Without a full processor simulation all you can get are guesses.  Whether those numbers are meaningful to you depends on what you are trying to accomplish with them.

Comment: doesnt matter, zero wait state or not.  arm cores and the peripherals around those and the chip vendors axi/amba interface, etc all determine execution speed.  If you want to know how fast something is on a particular board, run it on that board, otherwise it at best is only a rough guess and expected to be incorrect by some fact or 2x wrong 4x wrong 10x wrong, etc in either direction.

Comment: this is true for most pipelined architectures not just arm

Comment: deterministic architectures like the pics (not the mips pic of course) and 8051 and 68hc11, 6502, 8088, 8086, and a long list of others, you could easily make a tool that computes these execution times.

Comment: I am currently looking at `-fdump-rtl-all`.  Certainly gcc has some idea of how long instructions take.  I understand that the AMBA interface may vary.  That is **memory** is it not?  I want to assume that the core is feed with instructions.  ARM5 and earlier are certainly *deterministic*.  I am quite sure that they are all *deterministic*, maybe overly complex/deep pipeline is more appropriate?  I think is it unlikely to be 10x wrong.  If it is, then you need to look at the options you are passing to the compiler OR the compiler needs it's machine description updated.

Comment: A cycle count, plus an I/O count can give good information.  The CPU cycles will be balanced with the memory bus in a good routine.  Are you sure you guys are being defeatist?  Am I really off my rocker?  Will delete the question if so.

Comment: @BillPringlemeir: not off your rocker, and no need to delete the question, but the point is that newer processors, with large memory access latencies, are too non-determnistic for static analysis to be reliable. You end up spending time optimizing parts of code that do not affect actual performance, while ignoring parts that are crippling you (i.e. any destructive memory access patterns or thrashing branch predictors).

Comment: Take a look at GCC's machine descriptions (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Machine-Desc.html) to get a more accurate idea of what information GCC has about an instruction. In particular, GCC keeps track of delay slots required by an instruction, and processor pipelines provided by an architecture. It doesn't appear to be predicting instruction clock counts; it is simply using attributes of the instructions and pipeline to improve instruction ordering.

Comment: @mkfs I was thinking of [arm.c](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/arm/arm.c;hb=HEAD) in `gcc` and some of the *cost* information encoded there.  They appear to be instruction counts in some cases?  Not that they are *cycle accurate*, but they are what the compiler seems to use to select op-codes in some cases.

Comment: RE: arm.c -- that seems to provide information to the GCC optimizer, so you may be able to access it when compiling with -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=3 and/or -fdump-tree-vect. This information is not available in objdump, though, because it is not included in the binutils libopcodes module for ARM: http://repo.or.cz/w/binutils.git/blob/HEAD:/opcodes/arm-dis.c . That means you'd have to extract the cost-generation code from GCC, or (perhaps) pass GCC the raw asm and have it emit the cost info using the GCC -fdump options (if supported).

Comment: How can I do a full processor simulation?