# where can I find an overview of ARM processor instructions?

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

In vain I am looking for a well-arranged table of all ARM Cortex M3 instructions.

For example I see BNE and look into the table where I see what does how much time it takes and what the parameters of the variant, etc.

For example STM32F103, ST for this MCU published [PM0056 Programming manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/cd00228163-stm32f10xxx20xxx21xxxl1xxxx-cortexm3-programming-manual-stmicroelectronics.pdf)
Chapter 3 is The Cortex®-M3 instruction set , but in this section if not instruction BNE described, possible conclusion, MCU does not have this instruction. However, in the same manual, the BNE instruction and the BNE.W variant are used in two examples.

Sorry, but I have experience with Intel processors and there I have not yet to look for what instructions the processor supports.

Comment: Questions asking for external documentation are not on topic.  That said, refer to the Cortex M3 reference manual(s).

Comment: infocenter.arm.com  get the appropriate (armv7-m) architectural reference manual.  It is pipelined and arm sells cores not chips, so asking for timing doesnt make sense.

Comment: https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0337/e/instruction-timing/processor-instruction-timings  It is one cycle for not taken.  If you do branch, then it is dependent on the code memory and alignment of the branch instruction.  A vendor could theoretically re-write the M3 core and alter this timing.  That would be for an ARM IP M3 core.  If your M3 has TCM, then you can make better predictions on timing.

Comment: Page 92 on the PDF you linked documents `B` and `B{cond}`.  It's not going to enumerate every predicate condition repeatedly for every instruction you can put inside an IT block, or apparently even for conditional instructions outside IT blocks.

Comment: Related: [ARM cycle counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942436/post-process-objdump-disassemble-with-arm-cycle-counts).  What your asking for is valuable, but it is more difficult than you might first imagine.  I think developers become frustrated with this and react negatively to these questions.  It has always been the case that memory speeds impact timing; complexity increases with L1/L2, multiple pipelines, prediction, and out of order execution.  The M3 does not have most/any of those.