# Registering multiple Fast interrupt sources on ARM Linux

Tags: arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have been working with the Linux interrupt on ARM:

- `request_irq()` can be used to register an interrupt.

On a single interrupt line you can register multiple interrupts with `SHA_SHIRQ`, i.e normal IRQ.

- On a particular interrupt line does Linux allow to register multiple SA_INTERRUPT ?
- That is can we register multiple interrupt handlers for an ARM **fast interrupts** or `FIQ`s?

Comment: yes i mean .. FIQ of ARM. Kernel 3.2 series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the `IRQ`, the `FIQ` has a single point of entry from the vector table.  You must inspect the interrupt controller and branch based on a bit/number to handle the specific `FIQ`.  For the `FIQ`, this tends to negate the **banked registers** as both routines would have to share them.  It is possible to have one `FIQ` routine own the **banked registers** and the others explicitly save them.

The[current Linux FIQ code](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/kernel/fiq.c;hb=HEAD) supports stacking of FIQ handlers and not multiple simultaneous `FIQ` sources.  Your code can use [set_fiq_regs()](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/kernel/fiqasm.S;hb=HEAD) to initialize `FIQ` registers.  You may assign an interrupt controller base address and have code that inspects the `interrupt source` and branch to the appropriate handler.  **Note:**, the kernel doesn't provide any [communication mechanism](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/include/asm/fiq.h;hb=HEAD) with the `FIQ`.  You will have to write your own interlocks.  I think that the FIFO implementations should be `FIQ` safe as well as other [lock free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) kernel patterns.

**Edit:**  Here is a sample of `FIQ` in the mainline code.  It is an IMX SSI driver.
[SSI assembler](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/mach-imx/ssi-fiq.S;hb=HEAD), [Symbol interface](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/mach-imx/ssi-fiq-ksym.c;hb=HEAD), [main file](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=sound/soc/fsl/imx-pcm-fiq.c;hb=HEAD).  `FIQ` is also known as **soft DMA**.  The `FIQ` latency is very small and should allow high service frequencies.  Usually there is only a single device that needs this attention.  You can demultiplex in your handler (branch/function call/pointer on source number).  The reason a `FIQ` is often written in assembler is that *performance* is implicit if you use this.  Also, the `FIQ` will not normally be **masked** and it will increase `IRQ` **latency** for the rest of the system.  Making it faster by coding in assembler reduces the `IRQ` **latency**.

See also: [FIQ-IRQ difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973933/what-is-the-difference-between-fiq-and-irq-interrupt-system)

Comment: can we not use ----- request_irq()   --- to stack multiple FIQ interrupt handler on same interrupt line ?

Comment: No.  `request_irq()` is for IRQ only.  There is a completely different interface for `FIQ`.  Only the ARM has such a thing.  A major benefit is the **banked registers**.  Values don't have to constantly be reloaded.  You can use the **banked register** to hold state between `FIQ` interrupts.

Answer (score 1):

All the interrupt handlers which register on the same IRQ are put in list.  When the interrupt fires, the kernel calls each interrupt handler in turn (either last registered first or first registered first—I don't recall which offhand).  FAST_IRQ is not special in this regard.

It is the duty of each interrupt handler to check its hardware to see if it needs to handle anything.  If not, simply return so the next handler can look.

Comment: Means linux do not put any restriction on registering as many FIQ on a single line. ---> But what i have read that you should register only one FIQ handler & try to write it in assembly language. What do you say.